# Doubts about the standardization process that I should perform with a set of variables

Tags: categorical-data, standardization, categorical-encoding

I have a set of categorical variables that I need to encode between $[0,1]$ or $[-1,1]$ to solve a problem in which I have to compare their values with metrics like Euclidean Distance or the Dot product. These metrics require my variable to be in the mentioned ranges. As a first approach I represented each category $X_i$ of a variable as an integer $(1,2,\ldots)$, and then used the following formula to normalize them between $[-1,1]$:

$$X_i(\mbox{normalized}) = \frac{X_i - X_{min}}{X_{max}-X_{min}}$$

But this formula supposes that variables follow a uniform distribution which in my case is not true, as there is a great variance in some variables and a little variance in others. This means that in some variables a few categories contain the most part of the data, while the other categories are empty, or with a few outliers. For this reason I think my set follows a normal distribution which I have to standardize with mean 0 and variance 1 and after dividing each variable by its modulus, get a range of $[0,1]$ for them. But the problem is how should I code those variables, as they are categorical? The idea of represent them as integers (for example: red=1, yellow=2, green=3) would lead to strange results without sense for the mean (yellow in the example) and therefore also for the variance.

Which is the best way to code categorical variables?